# PosgreSQL - loop syntax

Tags: sql, postgresql, loops, for-loop, psql

I have the following loop (simplified for an example):

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
    l record;

  BEGIN
    FOR l IN SELECT id, country_id FROM logo LOOP
      WITH cs AS (
        INSERT INTO logo_settings (targeted) VALUES (true)
        RETURNING id
      )
      INSERT INTO logo_settings_targeted (logo_settings_id, country_id)
      VALUES 
      ( (SELECT id FROM cs),
        logo.country_id,
      );
    END LOOP;
  END;
END $$;
```

The body of a loop works fine. But if I wrap it into a loop (I would like to make records for all records from logo table) - it shows an error saying:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "END"
  Position: 712

END;
^
```

meaning the last EnND before `END $$;` which does not give much sense to me. I do not know what to fix to make it running. Any hints?

Comment: You don't need a loop for that. Not even PL/pgSQL

Comment: Did you forget to add the language at end?  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: the extra end after the end loop is causing it.

Comment: @Vivek: that's optional for a `do` block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one `end` to many. `end loop` closes the loop body:

```
DO $$
  DECLARE
    l record;

  BEGIN
    FOR l IN SELECT id, country_id FROM logo LOOP
      WITH cs AS (
        INSERT INTO logo_settings (targeted) VALUES (true)
        RETURNING id
      )
      INSERT INTO logo_settings_targeted (logo_settings_id, country_id)
      VALUES 
      ( (SELECT id FROM cs),
        logo.country_id,
      );
    END LOOP;
  END $$;
```

Comment: thanks, this was the case. I thought I have to close DO with end as well (dollars confused me). My first PostgreSQL loop :)

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to answer of @Andronicus, this is one possible way to do this without PL/pgsql:

[Click: demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3e33094a3221753540f955b016872dbb)

```
WITH countries AS  (
    SELECT id, country_id, 
        row_number() OVER ()                                        -- 1
    FROM logo
), ins_settings AS (
    INSERT INTO logo_settings(targeted)
    SELECT true FROM countries c
    RETURNING id
)
INSERT INTO logo_settings_targeted (logo_settings_id, country_id)
SELECT
  ins.id, c.country_id
FROM
  (SELECT id, row_number() OVER () FROM ins_settings) ins            -- 2
JOIN countries c ON c.row_number = ins.row_number
```

1. Put the first `SELECT` query (which you used for the loop) into a second CTE at the top.
2. The trick is, that you can join the outputs from the `logo` `SELECT` statement and the first insert. You can use the fact, that both outputs have the same number of rows. Simply add a column with a row count to both outputs. This can be done, for example, using the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html). As you can see, for the `logo` `SELECT` I already did this directly in the CTE (1), for the `INSERT` output I added this in a subquery (2). Now there are the same identifiers on both tables, which can be used for the join.
3. The join is the basis for the second `INSERT`.